# How to refresh the ListView after change the data with the DialogFragment?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, dialogfragment

I create a custom dialog with DialogFragment, and in the dialog, I can add some data to the SQLite database. Also, there is a listview in the main activity, which show the data of the SQLite.

I want to refresh the listview when I add the data to the database from the dialog. However, I have some problems.

I call the notifyDataSetChanged() in the onResume(), but the listview doesn't refresh when I dismiss the dialog. And if I press the home button and open the activity from the recent list, the listview will refresh.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listItem.clear();
    ServerListDB db = new ServerListDB(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.select();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("serverName", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(1)));
        map.put("serverIp", cursor.getString(2));
        map.put("serverPort", cursor.getString(3));
        listItem.add(map);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I add the log.v in the onPause(), and when the dialog show, the onPause() isn't called. Is this right for DialogFragment?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("Pause", "onPause() called!");
}
```

Comment: Is onResume even called, have you checked that?

Comment: onResume is not called when the dialog dismiss, but it will be called if I select the activity in the recent app list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog fragment will be tied to activity.
One simple approach is to notify your parent activity directly from dialog, as described here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Based on this, I would create an `Interface` that `Activity` must implement in order to get a callback when database is updated and to reload a list (or whatever):

```
public interface OnDBUpdatedListener {
    public void OnDBUpdated();
}
```

In your activity(s) you implement this interface:

```
public void OnDBUpdated() {
    // Reload list here
}
```

In your dialog fragment, when you save data or when you are dismissing the dialog, put the following code:

```
(OnDBUpdatedListener)getActivity()).OnDBUpdated()
```

Comment: My dialog is a custom dialog extends DialogFragment, this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have missed that you are telling about DialogFragment.

Comment: Thanks, but I have used another activity not the dialog to approach my requirement, I will try your way later. Anyway, thank you very much.