# ListView does not refresh after addition in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sugarorm

I have a list of objects (Intervals) stored in a SugarORM database that I'm adding to in a DialogFragment. The DialogFragment is shown from the MainActiviy and saves and creates the object in the DialogFragment itself and which then calls the DialogFragment's dialoglistener interface which communicates back to the MainActivity that then notify's the ListFragment (which is displayed in a tabbed ViewPager) that it should refresh the list. This, however, does not happen. The list does update after the app resumes or restarts

I've looked here
[How to refresh the ListView after change the data with the DialogFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321155/how-to-refresh-the-listview-after-change-the-data-with-the-dialogfragment)
and here
[Receive result from DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment)
With no success.

Thanks in advance!

Dialog Fragment code

```
public class NewIntervalDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private Button btnSave;
    private EditText etLabel;
    public NewIntervalDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

public static NewIntervalDialogFragment newInstance() {
    return new NewIntervalDialogFragment();
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_interval_dialog, container, false);

    //initiate all Variable and set up view 

    btnSave = (Button) newView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditDialogListener activity = (EditDialogListener) getActivity();
            if(activity==null){
                Log.d("NULL" ,"NULL ACTIVITY");
            }
            long workMins = npMinutesWork.getValue() * 60000;
            long restMins = npMinutesRest.getValue() * 60000;
            long workSecs = npSecondsWork.getValue() * 1000;
            long restSecs = npSecondsRest.getValue() * 1000;
            String label = etLabel.getText().toString();
            Interval newInterval = new Interval(label, workMins + workSecs, restMins + restSecs);
            newInterval.save();
            activity.onFinishEditDialog();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return newView;


}

public interface EditDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog();
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, IntervalListFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener, NewIntervalDialogFragment.EditDialogListener{


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    ViewPager mViewPager;

    static final String INTERVALS_KEY = "Saved Intervals";
    static final String WORKOUT_KEY = "Current Workout";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton mFab = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .withColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.logo_color))
                .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus))
                .withSize(72)
                .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
                .create();

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }



        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0), INTERVALS_KEY).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1), WORKOUT_KEY).commit();
    }

    void showDialog(){
        final DialogFragment newFragment = NewIntervalDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishEditDialog() {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            IntervalListFragment fragment =   (IntervalListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(INTERVALS_KEY);
            fragment.refresh();

    }
}
```

ListFragment Code

```
public class IntervalListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public int DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private ArrayList<Interval> intervals;
private IntervalListAdapter adapter;


/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public IntervalListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    try{
    intervals = (ArrayList<Interval>) Interval.listAll(Interval.class);}
    catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e){
        intervals = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }
    //Interval example = new Interval("Situps", 10000L, 50000L);
    //intervals.add(example);
    adapter = new IntervalListAdapter(getActivity(), intervals);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void refresh(){
    Log.d("REFRESH", "REFRESH CALLED");
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.refresh(Interval.listAll(Interval.class));

}
```

ListAdapter Code

```
public class IntervalListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Interval> {

public void refresh(List<Interval> intervals)
{
    this.intervals = intervals;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}e
```

Answer (score 0):

Add code

```
 adapter.setNotifyDataChanged()
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Yes, even for very short snippets.

Comment: I edited my original question to show that the listadapter's refresh method does call notifyDataSetChanged()